# DetailList fabric ui sorting issue React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im trying to use an example from fabric ui to to sort columns in a table.  However I am running into some issues because of my limited experience with react and react hooks.

the sorting function is as follows:

```
function  _copyAndSort<T>(items: T[], columnKey: string, isSortedDescending?: boolean): T[] {
        const key = columnKey as keyof T;
        return items.slice(0).sort((a: T, b: T) => ((isSortedDescending ? a[key] < b[key] : a[key] > b[key]) ? 1 : -1));
      }
    const _onColumnClick = (ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, column: IColumn): void => {

        const newColumns: IColumn[] = columns.slice();
        const currColumn: IColumn = newColumns.filter(currCol => column.key === currCol.key)[0];
        newColumns.forEach((newCol: IColumn) => {
          if (newCol === currColumn) {
            currColumn.isSortedDescending = !currColumn.isSortedDescending;
            currColumn.isSorted = true;
            setAnnouncedMessage(
                announcedMessage.concat('sorted')
            )
          } else {
            newCol.isSorted = false;
            newCol.isSortedDescending = true;
          }
        });
        const newItems = _copyAndSort(items, currColumn.fieldName!, currColumn.isSortedDescending);
        setColumns(
            {
                columns: newColumns,
            }
        )
    };
```

the columns are defined like this:

```
const [announcedMessage, setAnnouncedMessage] = useState('message: ');
    const theColumns = [
        {
            key: 'provider',
            name: 'Provider',
            fieldName: 'provider',
            minWidth: 150,
            maxWidth: 151,
            isResizable: true,
            isCollapsible: true,
            onColumnClick: _onColumnClick
        },
        {
            key: 'provider-display-name',
            name: 'Provider Display Name',
            fieldName: 'provider-display-name',
            minWidth: 150,
            maxWidth: 155,
            isResizable: true,
            isCollapsible: true,
        }
]

const [columns, setColumns] = useState(
        theColumns
    );
```

I didnt post all the columns the save space.

Im getting the following error doing the following:

```
(property) columns: IColumn[]
Argument of type '{ columns: IColumn[]; items: { key: number; provider: string; 'tag-line': string; 'provider-display-name': string; 'appointment-types': string; 'accept-online-bookings': string; 'accept-new-patients': string; edit: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<({ key: string; name: string; fieldName: string; minWidth: number; maxWidth: number; isResizable: boolean; isCollapsible: boolean; onColumnClick: (ev: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>, column: IColumn) => void; } | { ...; })[]>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'columns' does not exist in type 'SetStateAction<({ key: string; name: string; fieldName: string; minWidth: number; maxWidth: number; isResizable: boolean; isCollapsible: boolean; onColumnClick: (ev: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>, column: IColumn) => void; } | { ...; })[]>'.ts(2345)
```

when i try to set state:

```
setColumns(
            {
                columns: newColumns,
            }
        )
```

Also the methods for setting the announcement message doesnt seem  to be working as well. Id appreciat any help if available as Im pretty stuck getting this working

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was, I had to define theColumns as Type IColumn:

```
const theColumns:IColumn[] = [
        {
            key: 'provider',
            name: 'Provider',
            fieldName: 'provider',
            minWidth: 150,
            onColumnClick: _onColumnClick
        },
```